# Symfony 6 social login remember me not working

Tags: symfony, google-oauth, remember-me

I have updated my project to Symfony 6, and now my google login is not working as before. The remember me token is not working if I close the browser. In 5.4, I had written my security.yaml like this :

```
google:
  pattern: ^/connect/google
  guard:
    authenticators:
      - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
  logout:
    path: app_logout
    target: home
  remember_me:
    secret: "%env(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)%"
    lifetime: 604800
    always_remember_me: true
```

but now the cli tell me I need to change "guard". If I use custom_authenticator option, there are a lot of errors because I'm using SocialAuthenticator as you can see here : https://codeshare.io/Od84jx  If I remove the google part from security.yaml I don't have error, and register and login are working, but not remember me token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeeded, I share my solution for those who have the same problem.

So in symfony 5.4 to symfony 6.1, you need to use OAuth2Authenticator instead of SocialAuthenticator. You can follow the doc to write your GoogleAuthenticator : https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle#step-1-using-the-new-oauth2authenticator-class

Then you only need to add it in your custom_authenticator section in the security.yaml file. For example :

```
 main:
      switch_user: true
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      custom_authenticator: 
        - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
        - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
```

And then it will work if you already have your controller. (https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle#step-3-use-the-client-service)